# Quick Question Regarding Scaling: in Edit Mode, How Can One Scale Each CONNECTED Object Around Its Respective Origin?

Tags: modeling, scale

I'm fully aware that the option to set pivot point to individual origins exists. But even then, I have an issue that persists ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtMST3P4Lk8&feature=youtu.be) provided).

Let's say you have a pipe. You cut this pipe in such a way that the outline of the "open" ends are not parallel. Then you want to simply scale the width of this pipe (and not the length). Even after setting the pivot point to individual origins, the length of my pipe still changes when I'm scaling.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe just scaling only 2 axis and block the lenght axis from scaling?

Comment: unfortunately that wouldn't work here (one of the end "circles" has a component in all 3 main axis).